# Question on how bounties are awarded

Tags: support, bounty

When a question owner accepted and upvoted an answer but the bounty was not awarded manually until 7 days + grace period, will the full amount of the bounty offered to the person who answered the question, or does he need 2 votes at minimum for his answer when the bounty is expiring?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @yivi I have checked the wiki but that does not answered my question

Comment: It does, actually: _"f the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration."_

Comment: Oh, then the minimum of 2 vote condition not applies in this case. Thanks @yivi

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @yivi To be fair, that Help Center article is a bit ambiguous when it comes to this issue and needs to be reworded, IMO. The part you quoted should _at least_ be moved above the paragraph that talks about "a minimum score of 2" as in the Meta.SE answer that Robert has linked to above.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes, when following up the 3rd paragraph after the "minimum score of 2" rule, it makes a bit ambiguous to get the idea. Better if that can be moved up as the second paragraph. Sorry If I'm saying anything wrong but this is what I have gone through.

Answer (score -1):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/773001):

> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, **the bounty may be awarded automatically**.
>
> **If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer** that was posted after the bounty was started, **that answer is awarded the full bounty**.

So the number of votes on the answer wouldn't matter for the system to automatically award the full bounty, as long as the answer got accepted while the bounty was active.